# Can there be a problem for which we can prove there's a polynomial time algorithm and can prove that can't prove an algorithm is such?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

For a fiction story i imagined the following situation: there'd be a problem whose complexity depends on a natural number, for which a superpolynomial algorithm is known. Then a non-constructive proof is found that asserts there exists a polynomial algorithm for it. And then it is proved that given such an algorithm, it is impossible to prove that it works.

Is this situation known to be possible/impossible to happen? Has it ever happened / is there any known example of such example (even if it's an artificial problem designed to satisfy these conditions)?

Comment: What do you mean by proving in this context. Where would you want that proof to be possible, in PA, ZFC?

You can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578069/programming-and-zfc) some info about proving weather or not a program halts inside ZFC. Which is not exaclty your question but might be of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Part I: There probably aren't historical examples.**

Imagine an [$\mathsf{NP}$-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) problem $Q$ with *at most one* reasonable polynomial-time algorithm, $A$.  If [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) fails to prove that $A$ solves $Q$, then [$\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem) is independent of (unprovable from) ZFC.

In section 3.1 of [this paper](https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/pnp.pdf) Scott Aaronson analyzes this possibility quite extensively; he ultimately concludes that such a fact would be (1) unprecedented (2) far beyond known techniques of proof and (3) very unlikely.  (Fun fact: such a circumstance would leave $\mathsf{NP}$ [not much harder](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/wwwb/cgi-bin/tr-get.cgi/1991/CS/CS0699.revised.pdf) than $\mathsf{P}$.)

Now, I made some strong assumptions to conclude that $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$ is unprovable.  For example, there are still hard (superpolynomial-time-requiring) problems that are not $\mathsf{NP}$-complete.  Or one can imagine an $\mathsf{NP}$-complete problem with many candidate solutions from $\mathsf{P}$, a few of which ZFC cannot prove to be actual solutions.  Or

> then it is proved that given such an algorithm, it is impossible to prove that it works.

might describe a *proof sketch*: a description of how to turn a description of $A$ into a proof that "ZFC cannot prove $A$ solves $Q$," but which uses different axioms of ZFC depending on $A$, and so cannot prove "for any polynomial-time $A$, ZFC cannot prove the statement '$A$ solves $Q$'".

But if a problem of that sort had already come up, I think Aaronson would have mentioned it.

**Part II: An artificial example**

It turns out that the use of $\mathsf{P}$ in your problem is a red herring.

To begin, note that ZFC is not known consistent; moreover this likely [cannot be known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Second_incompleteness_theorem).  This is a separate question from whether *proofs* that ZFC is consistent exist: if ZFC is in fact *inconsistent*, then such a proof does exist.

Moreover: if ZFC is inconsistent, then ZFC proves [any true (and any false!) fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion).  So the statement

> it is proved that given such an algorithm, it is impossible to prove that it works

probably omits some qualifiers.  (It *must* omit some qualifiers if, as the mathematical community believes, ZFC is consistent.)  A reasonable reduction would be:

> it is proved that, given such an algorithm **and assuming ZFC consistent**, then it is impossible to prove **from ZFC** that the algorithm works.

Finally, recall from the proof of Gödel's incompleteness theorem that natural numbers can [encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering) ZFC proofs.

Now consider the following problem:

> Check the input number to see if it is the smallest number that encodes a proof that ZFC is inconsistent.  Return $1$ if so; else return $0$.

I call this "problem $\Omega$."

One can "unravel" Gödel's proof to find a computer program $A$ that performs such a check.  Since each number encodes at most a finite-length proof, that computer program always halts, although it might take a long time to do so.  $A$ is your superpolynomial algorithm solving $\Omega$.

If ZFC is assumed consistent, then $A(n)=0$ for all $n$; and the computer program "return $0$" is clearly in $\mathsf{P}$.  Otherwise, $A(n)=0$ for all-but-one $n$ (say, $n_d$), and the program "if the input is $n_d$, return $1$, else return $0$" is *also* in $\mathsf{P}$.  This paragraph is your nonconstructive proof that there is a polynomial-time algorithm solving $\Omega$.

But *which* algorithm solves $\Omega$ is not provable from ZFC, because the consistency of ZFC is unprovable from ZFC.

Wait!  That's not quite right: if ZFC is inconsistent, then we can prove that the correct algorithm is in fact correct (because we can prove that *any* algorithm is correct).  The correct statement is:

> Gödel's incompleteness theorem combined with the definition of $A$ proves:
>
> > if (1) ZFC holds and (2) ZFC is consistent, then ZFC cannot prove which polynomial-time algorithm solves $\Omega$.

But that is the reduction I mentioned at the beginning of this section, so we're done.